# Accessibility focus goes in space in between the cells in a table view

Tags: ios, accessibility

I am using a table view to show my data. There is no separator view in between the cells but when I switch on the voice over, the focus after on the cell, goes in the space between the two cells ans then on another swipe goes to the next cell.
I am not able to figure out what's going wrong. 
The tableView is being imported from another framework, where it is working fine.
The separatorStyle for tableView is set to none.

Comment: Can you show your attempt please? what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out the problem.
In the framework where tableView is populated, array.filter{ !$0.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).isEmpty } was missing at one place where the tableView was passed with the array as data.
so, that focus was on cells with empty spaces as data.
Thank you